# If $T$ is self-adjoint and $\langle T(u),u \rangle > 0$ for every $u$ in $K$, $u\neq0$ then $T = R^2$ for some self-adjoint non-singular operator $R$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, positive-definite, self-adjoint-operators

it´s my first question here and it´s because I can´t find the way to stablish the equivalence between those statements. I don´t see how the inner product or the fact that T is a self-adjoint operator could give me the operator R that i need.
My attemp was trying to use the matrix representation of T and show that that matrix is positive definite and diagonalizable, then I could extract the square root matrix and then argument that that matrix is the representation of a non-singular linear operator (since T is non-singular) and that is self-adjoint. but I can´t propose the first matrix.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Positive definite matrices are diagonalizable.

Comment: What is $T$? A matrix? A general operator? A compact operator?

Comment: T is a linear operator in a vectorial space V